# How do I fix Key error with azure cosmos db?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

here is my code:

```
endpoint = os.environ["https://davidjohns.documents.azure.com/"]
DATABASE_NAME = "cosmicworks"
CONTAINER_NAME = "products"
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = CosmosClient(url=endpoint, credential=credential)
```

And here is the error I am receiving:

```
 endpoint = os.environ["https://davidjohns.documents.azure.com/"]
  File "/Users/davidjohns/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'https://davidjohns.documents.azure.com/'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is it stored in your environ? The key you are using looks more like a value than a key.

Comment: `os.environ[]` is giving you access to environment variables. You have to use the *name* of the environment variable, not the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I tried same code and got same error:

[image]

> ```
> raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'COSMOS_ENDPOINT'
> ```

The above error suggest the **`COSMOS_ENDPOINT`** is not found in the environment variables.

To set an environment variable you can use below command in your terminal:

```
$env:COSMOS_ENDPOINT = "https://cosmos-account.documents.azure.com:443/"
```

**Console:**
[image]

I used the sample code to create container with environment variable.

**Code:**

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient,Partitionkey
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import os

ENDPOINT = os.environ["COSMOS_ENDPOINT"]
KEY = os.environ["COSMOS_KEY"]
client=CosmosClient(ENDPOINT,credential=KEY)

database=client.get_database_client("database987")
Partition_key=Partitionkey(Path='/Name')
container=database.create_container(id="test",partition_key=Partition_key)
print("Container created!!!")
```

**Console:**
The above code executed and created container successfully.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart - Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL client library for Python | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-python?tabs=azure-portal%2Cpasswordless%2Cwindows%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Csync)

Comment: Important reading: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Aside from that: the OP's issue is just a typo, using key value instead of key name. No need for such an answer, no need to prove you recreated the error (that just makes the answer look much more complex) and no need to show the OP how to view collections and data in Cosmos DB (this has nothing to do with the question)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ran the $env:COSMOS_ENDPOINT="<endpoint>" and got the error "zsh: command not found: :COSMOS_ENDPOINT". Any sugestions?

Comment: @David Johns If you are using zsh on macOS or Linux, try using the export command instead: `export  COSMOS_ENDPOINT="<endpoint>"`